# Laravel 5.2 wordpress integration on laravel forge using nginx

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, integration

I have a laravel 5.2 web app built and hosted on laravel forge.  No problem so far, but my client has asked me to install a wordpress blog on the app.  So far, I have downloaded the wordpress files and have made and installed them in the public/blog folder.  I want to see the blog at http://www.example.com/blog.  I have read other answers about needing to change my nginx.conf file because of issues with permalinks?  I want to enable permalinks and have a clean install of wordpress so what changes do i need to make to my nginx.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add some rules for your `Wordpress` directory (and all other directories you want to use) **before** `Laravel` rules.

For `nginx` rules will look like:

```
location /blog/index.php(/.*)?$ {        
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/index.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location /blog/ { 
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /blog/index.php last;    
        }
    try_files $uri $uri/ blog/index.php?args; 
}
```

Please look here for a [solution](http://www.jeffmould.com/2016/02/21/exclude-subdirectory-laravel5-routing/).

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your answer, I have looked at the solution you provided too, but where in my nginx.conf file would i place the edits?  Attach to the end?

Comment: No, you should use these rules before Laravel's rules. Please click the link provided in my answer, you'll see full example of `Wordpress + Laravel` nginx config file. So, put this before `location / {` line.